# Jupyter Notebook Not Updating When Using Docker with Volumes

Tags: python, bash, docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have set up a Docker environment to run Jupyter Notebook using a Dockerfile and a bash script to start the notebook. Additionally, I have created a `.gitignore` file to ignore certain elements. The issue I am facing is that Jupyter Notebook is not updating when I make changes to the notebooks in the `notebooks` directory on my host machine.

Directory Structure on My Host Machine:

```
my_project/
│
├── Dockerfile
├── start_notebook.sh
├── .gitignore
├── requirements.txt
└── notebooks/
    ├── notebook1.ipynb
    ├── notebook2.ipynb
    ├── notebook3.ipynb
    └── ...
```

Here's the content of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM jupyter/base-notebook:python-3.11

# Copy the requirements.txt file to the container
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# Install the dependencies from the requirements.txt file
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Expose Jupyter Notebook port
EXPOSE 8888

# Copy the notebooks directory to the container's /app directory
COPY notebooks /app/notebooks

# Run Jupyter Notebook on container startup
CMD ["jupyter", "notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--port=8888", "--no-browser", "--allow-root"]
```

And here's the content of my bash script (`start_notebook.sh`):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current directory path
CURRENT_DIR=$(pwd)

# Build the Docker image using the Dockerfile in the current directory
docker build -t my_jupyter_image .

# Create a Docker volume for the ipynb files in the current directory
docker volume create --name notebook_volume --opt type=none --opt device="$CURRENT_DIR/notebooks" --opt o=bind

# Run the Docker container with the Jupyter Notebook image and disable login
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 \
           --name my_jupyter_container \
           -v notebook_volume:/app/notebooks \
           my_jupyter_image \
           start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.token=''
```

And my `.gitignore` file contains the following entries:

```
# Ignore __pycache__ folder
./notebooks/__pycache__/

# Ignore .ipynb_checkpoints folder
.ipynb_checkpoints/

# Readme file 
README.md
```

Even though I make changes to the notebooks in the `notebooks` directory on my host machine, the changes are not reflected when I access Jupyter Notebook through the browser at `http://localhost:8888`. The notebooks appear to be stuck in their previous state.

How can I resolve this issue and make sure that Jupyter Notebook updates properly when I modify the notebooks in the `notebooks` directory on my host machine? Is there something I am missing or need to configure differently in my Docker setup?

Answer (score 1):

You need the additional environment vars passed to the container - if you are using a jupyter stack, it runs as user jovyan.

So add the following to your environment:

```
NB_USER="${USER}"
NB_UID=1000
CHOWN_HOME="yes"
CHOWN_EXTRA="work"
CHOWN_EXTRA_OPTS="-R"
```